# css :after not appearing in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have a tabbed paged in which there is an arrow after the selected tab. In chrome and ie this works fine. But in Firefox the element does not appear. Is some reason why firefox does not render this css? How would i fix the issue with firefox?

```
li.current::after {      
    color: transparent;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    border-width: 15px 15px 0px;
    /* background-position-y: -100px; */
    border-style: solid;
    /* border-color: #30B3EE transparent; */
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')!important;
    background-position-x: -49px;
    width: 0;
}
```

My jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/okwhyrpc/10/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is due to the `background-position-x` property, which is [not implemented](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=550426) (yet?) on Firefox: the possibility to change a single background axis — unfortunately — is not currently supported in this browser.

Use instead `background-position: -49px 0` ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bg3dnLLa/))

Comment: I'm confused about that. It was never part of the standard, rejected at one time, then accepted just a few months ago, but I can't find it in the draft. I'd be wary of using this.